How to resolve storybook nextjs project error - you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
I'm using storybook 7 and trying to create stories from existing react components which I'm importing from bit. So while creating stories, Im referring a file where some json variable has been declared as any like below.
file.ts
export const contentCard2UpWithIsCTARowProp: any = {
 analytics: {
  msg: "NET",
   description: "TEST",
 }
}


My main.ts:
const config: StorybookConfig = {
 stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
 addons: [],
 framework: {
  name: "@storybook/nextjs",
  options: {},
 }
}

If I remove the any, it is working fine. But I cannot do that. I have tried many solutions mentioned  like updating  "jsx": "react" in tsconfig.json, tried installing @babel/core & its dependency modules . Can anyone please help me with this.
